# Deploy asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC web application. I need to deploy it which consists of:
1. Changing some of Web.config sections
2. Building under Release configuration
3. Copying to my deployment server (optional)

What are the ways to automate this process?

Comment: @rlb.usa, locally - yes. On production server - currently yes, but want to get rid of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Changing some of Web.config sections
```

Use the [web.config transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) you can implemnt it by modifing the Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config in your web project

```
2. Building under Release configuration
3. Copying to my deployment server (optional)
```

[This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx) should help. Read also [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/442448.aspx) about the publish thing

Answer (score 1):

We use continuous integration via Jenkins/Hudson to build and a task in it to deploy to staging or production that uses msdeploy in a batch script.

For building, our parameters for msbuild for release builds are:

`/Target:Clean;Build /Property:Configuration=Release`

It does take a while to figure out the msdeploy options but it is worth looking into (it's what Visual Studio is using behind the scenes to do the deploy if you use the GUI-based approach).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of building under release configuration & copying to your deployment server you can use MS-Build alongside a tool like Team City / Team Build to automate the process.

Here is a great post to get yourself up and running: [How to use MSBuild to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228840/how-to-use-msbuild-to-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-application)