# Testing ASP.NET site using WatiN. Is it possible to programmatically deploy an ASP.net site locally?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, testing, watin

I would like to use [WatiN](http://watin.org/) to test the functionality of a website I'm developing.  Ideally, I would programmatically deploy the website (asp.net MVC3) before the tests start running, and then refresh the data before each test.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here about using MSBuild to deploy web projects. Getting your application into automated deploy on build success (read: Continuous Integration) is really nice.

MSBuild - [How to use MSBuild to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228840/how-to-use-msbuild-to-deploy-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Using NUnit, for refreshing the data before each test you can decorate a method with [Setup] (or [TestFixtureSetup]) to run code once before each test (or once before each group of tests).  I use this for cases that require specific data setup and it works like a champ.  I'm assuming other XUnit frameworks have similar mechanisms in place.

Setup - http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10