# Use TypeScript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

How to effectively use TypeScript with ASP.NET MVC?

I want my IDE to do the following actions when I run my project:

1. Compile (interpret) my typescript files (*.ts) by typescript compiler.
2. Minimize all the javascript files.
3. Obviously run my app :).

How to configure IDE to do all the steps automatically on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this [address](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2012/10/02/using-typescript-in-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx), you will find that the current preview version of TypeScript is not providing a project template for ASP.NET MVC 4 projects. But you can edit your csproject file with the following code:

```
<ItemGroup>

    <TypeScriptCompile Include="$(ProjectDir)\**\*.ts" />

</ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">

   <Exec Command="&amp;quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\

   Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&amp;quot; 

  @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />

  </Target>
```

It allows you to compile all TypeScript when building ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

About the optimizing :

I suggest you separate the JavaScript files of your project and add references them into your master page like at this post : [How can I automatically compress and minimize JavaScript files in an ASP.NET MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224292/best-way-to-automatically-compress-and-minimize-javascript-files-in-an-asp-net-m).

You can also use the "[bundling](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-bundling-and-minification)" with the Razor view.  Personally I use that and it works perfectly.

Comment: If you are using MVC bundles, optimisation is disabled in debug mode and enabled in release mode by default.

Comment: Just reference the generated JS files in BundleConfig to handle the bundling & minification.