# Combine and minimize css with title and rel attributes

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, compression, minimize

I have been reading about css and js compression and minimizing. In particular that post [Concatenate and minify JavaScript on the fly OR at build time - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890561/concatenate-minify-js-on-the-fly-or-at-build-time-asp-net-mvc) Im developing a MVC ASP.NET application and using Combres for minimizing and compress files. I'm not too happy and now i'm evaluating MVCScriptManager as suggested by Scott in the post mentioned.

However i have a problem with my css files: In my site i allow the user to change the style of the page, i acomplish this task defining different stylesheets.

To change the style when user click a button, i enable the proper style using the "title" attribute of the link tag:

```
$('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i) {
   this.disabled = true;
   if (this.getAttribute('title') == styleName) this.disabled = false;
});
```

And in the head section of my page what i have is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/green.css" title="Green" media="screen" />    
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/cyan.css" title="Cyan" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/orange.css" title="Orange" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/navy.css" title="Navy" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/purple.css" title="Purple" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/pink.css" title="Pink" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/css/wine.css" title="Wine" media="screen" />
```

The problem is when i combine the stylesheets i cannot rely on the title and rel attributes to do the switch. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Hi!  I'm the author of Combres.  Can you let me know the reason why you're not happy with Combres?  That would help me know how I should improve the library to make it more useful for others.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Combres is great but sometimes i have to compress the js files by myself because Combres fails to do that. I have been thinking that probably i'm doing something wrong but i couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, really you should be loading the CSS files on demand.

So that if the user chooses pink, the pink.css `<link>` would be inserted as the last element in `<head>`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about that. Now what i do is load the stylesheet when the page loads and then when the user changes the style i change dynamically the href attribute with the stylesheet requested! I want to vote for your answer but i can't since i don't have 15 points of reputation!