# Setting Visual Studio to automatically minifying using Ajax Minifier

Tags: visual-studio-2010, minify, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I use VS 2010 I would like at the pressing of `Build Button` have all CSS and .JS files minified.

Following this [article](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/10/16/using-the-new-microsoft-ajax-minifier.aspx) all is working great for JS... adding some extra code for the CSS (pasted below) I'm not able to Minifying the CSS. What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<ItemGroup>
    <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;Scripts\*.js" />
    <JS Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css;Scripts\*.css" />
</ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin SourceFiles="@(JS)" SourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" TargetExtension=".min.js" />
    <AjaxMin SourceFiles="@(CSS)" SourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" TargetExtension=".min.css" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to run Ajax Minifier as post-build in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539127/unable-to-run-ajax-minifier-as-post-build-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution to my problem, more resource here

[Unable to run Ajax Minifier as post-build in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539127/unable-to-run-ajax-minifier-as-post-build-in-visual-studio)

http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AjaxMinTask

Also very interesting:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81317/Automatically-compress-embedded-JavaScript-resourc.aspx?msg=3802401&display=Mobile

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
        <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;Scripts\*.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <CSS Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin
        JsSourceFiles="@(JS)"  JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".min.js"
        CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".min.css"  />
</Target>
```

Comment: Also here is a list of <AjaxMin> tag properties and default values:
http://nzbart.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-ajax-minifier-as-msbuild-task.html

Answer (score 0):

On my project file I used "UsingTask" instead of "Import" and it's working:

```js
<UsingTask TaskName="AjaxMin" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\packages\AjaxMin.5.14.5506.26202\tools\net40\AjaxMinTask.dll" />
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
   <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\*.min.js;Scripts\*.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
   <CSS Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <AjaxMin
   JsSourceFiles="@(JS)"  JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".min.js"
   CssSourceFiles="@(CSS)" CssSourceExtensionPattern="\.css$" CssTargetExtension=".min.css"  />
 </Target>
```