# Stand-alone way to bundle style/javascript

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

In asp.net MVC, included a built-in integrated javascript bundle with `BundleCollection`. With it, you simply define which resources to add to bundle and render it on the view.

Now I want to make something like javascript/css portal which handle the resources and expose it via webapi.

Is there any stand-alone built-in way to bundle and minify, and return it as string?

Comment: Why not use a standalone MVC application?

Comment: It will be used across applications in integrated system. Well, enterprise for it to sound fancy enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I would bundle and minify shared resources at build time.

I have referenced virtual folders in mvc bundles for multiple applications before and it is possible, but I found it a bit clunky.

There is a build time solution here - basically have a post-build event running yuicompressor etc:
[Concatenate and minify JavaScript on the fly OR at build time - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890561/concatenate-and-minify-javascript-on-the-fly-or-at-build-time-asp-net-mvc)

There are also some runtime solutions there with the creation of a HTTPHandler, etc

Comment: I have seen the answer in you link but it doesn't answer my question. The runtime solution works in asp.net webform not in mvc. Furthermore, I am thinking in managing library version which will require runtime bundling not build time bundling.