# Cookieless rendering of a side bar with links enabled based on a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have an MVC 4 site that renders a left sidebar with a bunch of menu links on it.  When the user signs in, they are directed to a page where they search for someone.  Once they've selected someone and submitted the form, an `id` cookie gets set.

This `id` determines whether or not various links in the sidebar menu are enabled, as it is a required parameter for many of the actions that those links lead to.  The menu itself, since it is on every page of the site, is set up in the _Layout partial:

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="left-menu">
        @Html.Action("Display", "Menu", new { Area = "" })
    </div>
    <div id="mainbody">
        <section>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

`Display` returns a partial view representing the sidebar menu.  Since I'm rendering the menu sidebar in the _Layout, I don't have a model to work with.  Is there any way I can get the parameter to my menu partial view **without** using a cookie?

Comment: @Scott Selby - How?  This menu is rendered on every view in the site (via the _Layout).  Where would I set my ViewBag("id") value?  Every public GET action?

Comment: Your id parameter should came from somewhere. If not from a cookie then from where? Where can you calculate this id?

Comment: @nemesv - The id parameter comes from the database after the user does a search and selects it.

Comment: @nemesv - and yes, that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a hidden field and viewbag

```
Public ActionResult Index(){
ViewBag.id = // set your id initially 

}
```

if javascript/jquery is ok with you...

```
$(function(){
var myID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.id));
$('#hidID').val(myID);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidID" id="hidID" />
```

Then.. Display Action

```
Public ActionResult Display(int hidID){    
// this will be current id,
// if id is reset , pass the new one to viewbag , jquery will reset hidden field on client
}
```

Comment: Would you put the hidden field and the javascript in the _Layout partial view?

Comment: I was under the impression that putting javascript in partial views was bad practice.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6901351/27457

Comment: that is not what that question was refering to, they meant don't add a link to jquery file in partial view , all references to css and js files should be in the head in the layout ,  you can put js code anywhere you want