# How to debug a script inside partial view that load by javascript in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, partial-views, jquery-load

When I loaded html file that contains javascript code by using the following code

$("#containerId").load("@Url.Action("ActionName")");

I couldn't find it in the chrome source tab 
I find out chrome renames js-loaded file to something like "VM27123" that the number changed by every refresh and chrome does not show these files in search result

so how can I find them and set breakpoint on it?

Answer (score 4):

[omatase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315533/5697765):

use the syntax:

```
//# sourceURL=fileName.cshtml
```

immediately after opening your script tag. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //# sourceURL=fileName.cshtml
    function foo() {}
</script>
```

and you can find your javascript in sources tab on debug mode by fileName