# How to load a javascript from partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**I have created a partial view "_Test1" in mvc 4.0.**

[image]

**With the help of a controller I am calling my partial view.**

```
private ActionResult MyView()
{
    return PartialView("_Test1");
}
```

When I debug I don't get any error, I assume that my partial view has been loaded successfully through controller. Now with the help of this partial view, I have to call a javascript. Which gives me an error **"Unexpected character '$'"**. Please refer he screenshot below :-

[image]

**Can someone help ?**

Comment: `$` is for jquery I pressumed. Please add the jquery library in your main view

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885990/linking-javascript-libraries-in-user-controls/886184#886184

Comment: Thanks Smit for sharing me the link.. It worked..